# Using \scshape and \bfseries together

Tags: fonts, formatting, bold, small-caps

A very obvious one I suspect, but when I try to do the following the small caps are over-ruled by the boldface, so I get lowercase rhubarb rhubarb. Is there an easy way to get `\scshape\bfseries`?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}    
\begin{document}
\bfseries\scshape rhubarb rhubarb
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need a font which provides such a combination.

Comment: Not all fonts have boldface small caps; in particular the Computer Modern fonts don't have this combination.

Comment: thanks @egreg. Is there a reference document where I can find which fonts do?

Comment: I've never seen such a document, but I've seen a few fonts that do have bold small caps (e.g. Minion, Scala) or bold faux small caps (e.g. the TeX Gyre fonts).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some fonts support this. The incomplete list is:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
%\usepackage{mathpazo}
%\usepackage{newtxtext}
%\usepackage{charter}
%\usepackage{kpfonts}
%\usepackage{fourier}
%\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
%\usepackage{pxfonts}
\begin{document}
\bfseries\scshape Rhubarb Rhubarb
\end{document}
```