# How to make the title of paragraph bold and uppercase at the same time?

Tags: fonts, sectioning

I cannot make tim bold and uppercase at the same time,
if I do this:

```
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
{\normalfont\scshape\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
```

they are bold but not uppercase

if I do

```
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
{\normalfont\scshape}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
```

then they are uppercase but not bold.

How could I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Note that `\scshape` doesn't make the text uppercase, but in small caps. If you want to use `\scshape` and `\bfseries` together, you have to choose a font that supports that combination. For more info see [Using \scshape and \bfseries together](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98576/27635)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
{\bfseries\scshape}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Some} text
\end{document}
```