# New command to bold within small caps

Tags: fonts

I'd like to have a command to write a word in all small caps of equal size (no initial large capital letter), with a specified central portion in bold.

```
\mkboldcaps{Aver}{ag}{e}
```

would produce the output
    AVER **AG** E (no spaces)

So far, I have the following command, which makes a word into all small caps of the small size:

```
\newcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}
```

The trouble comes when I try to combine these. In the following command,

```
\newcommand{\makeboldcaps}[3]{\smallcaps{#1}{\textbf{#2}}\smallcaps{#3}}
```

the middle portion is successfully made bold, but it is not in small caps. Adding a \textsc to the central portion messes up the rest of the command. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Very few font families have boldface small caps.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! So this means that there's no real way to accomplish the above in the way I suggested right? I'll have to locate a font family that actually has boldface small caps.

Comment: If you want the standard Computer Modern fonts (actually a clone thereof), then `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` will suffice.

Comment: Relevant: [Small Caps and Bold Face](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27411/5764); [Using `\scshape` and `\bfseries` together](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98576/5764)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to ensure that the font family used has boldface small caps. The standard Computer Modern font family hasn't them, but the European Modern fonts do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\mkboldcaps}[3]{%
 {% keep the font change local
  \scshape\MakeLowercase{#1}\textbf{\MakeLowercase{#2}}\MakeLowercase{#3}%
 }%
}

\begin{document}
\mkboldcaps{Aver}{ag}{e}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you need that your TeX distribution includes the CMSuper font package, or you'll get the fonts in bitmap form.

Comment: Why the repetition? Why not `\scshape\MakeLowercase{#1\textbf{#2}#3}` ?

Comment: @pst Why not? I prefer `\textbf{\MakeLowercase{...}}` that makes clearer what's wanted. But it's just a matter of preferences.

Comment: OK! For me it's less clear when it seems like there are *three* texts that should be lowercases, but that is obviously not universal then.