# Bold Small Caps for Font Without

Tags: bold, small-caps

I am trying with no success to create text using bold small caps for the Latin Modern Roman font. The whole manner in which fonts are handled in TeX really confuses me, so my knowledge on any commands and ways to manipulate it are limited to `\textit`, `\textbf`, `\scshape`, `\bfseries`, the size commands, and `\setmainfont`.

I found that because there is no bold small caps font included in LMR, I could not make bold small caps right away. Trying the methods linked at the bottom produced these results. 
**Open Type Large**
[image: Open Type Large]

**Open Type Small**
[image: Open Type small]

**T1 Large**
[image: T1 Large]

**T1 Small**
[image: T1 Small]

As my document is all set up for using `fontspec` I cannot get the second solution to work and the first solution has a severe problem of its own, which can be seen in "open type small" as the blocky looking text.

So I had two ideas, one was to look for a font with bold small caps, (which I found called Trajan Pro). However I don't know how to implement it as by bold small caps font.

The second solution which is what I really want to try is to make latex automatically increase the font size of the first letter in every word. Perhaps a new command like...

```
{\bfscaps This is an Example}
```

At the end of the day I need this to work with `titlesec` to define subsubsections and the like. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do either of these methods?

[How to use all variants of Latin Modern Roman with fontspec?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79086/how-to-use-all-variants-of-latin-modern-roman-with-fontspec)

[Choosing font for bold small caps (or any other particular family+series+shape combination)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22240/choosing-font-for-bold-small-caps-or-any-other-particular-familyseriesshape-c)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194241/how-to-bold-custom-calligraphic-text, if you are willing to use overstroked glyphs to "simulate" it.

Comment: more suggestions in [Small Caps and Bold Face](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27411/579) and [New command to bold within small caps](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172544/579)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was asked by me a very long time ago when I was just starting to learn latex.

Nearly 5 years later, and knowing how to ask for what I actually wanted, the best answer to this question can be found here.

**Fontspec help, combining fonts:**
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/503836/35515

Given the large number of views this question has received because of its title keywords, I wanted to direct future viewers to this answer.