# Both \textsc and \textbf for sections using Modern CV

Tags: moderncv

Well, all is in the title. I don't want to use something like loading `fontenc` or anything like this, just enable `\section{\textbf{\textsc{Experience}}}`

EDIT :

Well thanks to all of you, I tried that :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[inner=1.2cm,outer=1.2cm,top=0.4cm,bottom=0.4cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{sourcesanspro}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\bfseries\scshape}

\firstname{\Large{Aaaa}}
\familyname{\Large{\textsc{Bbbb}}}
\title{\normalsize Iiiiiiiiiiiii }
\address{\textbf{113 iiiii}}{\textbf{000 Vvvvv}}  
\mobile{\textbf{0000000}}             
\email{aaaaaa@aaa.fr} 
\extrainfo{\textbf{bla bla}}  

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\maketitle

\section{Experience}
\end{document}
```

Perhaps it works. "Experience" seem to be normal in bold. Using "fontenc" as I don't like that sourseanpro doesn't work (for me). What I need is result IN BOLD when deleting sourceandpro and renewcomand line and using \textsc in section.

Well I'm not satisfied and how to use "sans" option properly ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: "Just enable" requires a font that supports **CAPITALIZED BOLD** font. And this may require [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec).

Comment: most font sets do not have bold caps and small caps font. If teh font does not exist, latex can not select it.

Comment: Please mark lines of code (not inline code but stretches of it) by indenting the code by 4 spaces. Easy way: highlight and click the `{}` button. Code tags do not work properly (e.g. you do not get something you can scroll and code is not formatted as a block).

Comment: To be honest, I don't really understand your question. If you delete the `\renewcommand` line then of course sections won't be typeset in bold because you are deleting the command which tells LaTeX to make them bold. (Unless bold is default for the class, which is presumably not the case or this wouldn't be a problem.) And it isn't clear what you mean by `sourcesanspro` not working. Do you mean that you get an error? Or that it compiles but the output is unexpected? Or that you just don't like the font? You say you are using `fontenc` but that's not in your code.

Comment: You definitely do not want to format section titles by including explicit formatting in the argument to `\section`. Whatever formatting you want, the `\renewcommand` etc. is definitely the way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

`\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\bfseries\scshape}` will do the job, but as Werner said, you need a suitable font. `sourcesanspro` has bold small caps, for example (and I like it).

As karlkoeller says, since that's a sans serif font, you need to pass the class option `sans`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
```

If you want a serif font instead, you could load the `bold-extra` package, or choose a font from those in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98581/61789

Comment: Also you have to load `moderncv` with the option `sans`