# Changing content of \listoftheorems and hyperlinking to text

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, theorems, amsthm, thmtools

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{libertine} % allows bf sc fonts http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98581/104449
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=\topsep, spacebelow=\topsep,
  headfont=\libertine\bfseries\scshape,
  notefont=\libertine\bfseries\scshape,
  headindent=-1em,
  headpunct=\newline,
  numberwithin=chapter,
  notebraces={- }{}
]{mythmstyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mythmstyle]{thm}
\declaretheorem[style=mythmstyle, title=Defn]{defn}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\listoftheorems[ignoreall, show={thm}]
\begingroup               % Temporarily disable \clearpage to show both lists on one page
  \let\clearpage\relax    % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14511/104449
  \renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of Definitions}
  \listoftheorems[ignoreall, show={defn}]
\endgroup


\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{}
\begin{thm}[My first theorem]
\end{thm}

\begin{defn}[My first definition]
\end{defn}

\chapter{}
\begin{thm}[My second theorem]
\end{thm}

\begin{defn}[My second definition]
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

Here's what the output of this looks like:

[image]

I want to get rid of the Thm/Defn prefixes and the enclosing parenthesis for each entry in List of Theorems and List of Definitions. i.e. I'd like the first entry to be like:

```
1.1 My first theorem ...................................... 1
```

I also want the entries in the list to hyperlink to the page (and ideally the exact location) of the referenced theorem/definition.

Does anybody know how to do this or have tips on what documentation to read? I looked at [thmtools](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/thmtools/thmtools.pdf) documentation for `\listotheorems` but I was unable to figure out how to change the content of each line entry.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is hardcoded in `thm-listof.sty`, but I'll take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `name={...}` option to the definition in the `\declaretheoremstyle` command defaults to the theorem name, or it's possible to say `name={}` to remove the prefix in the List of Theorems, but this has an effect to the body-text display as well. (It's not the best solution)

The parentheses can be removed by redefining `\thmtformatoptarg` to be

```
\renewcommand{\thmtformatoptarg}[1]{#1}
```

Loading `hyperref` as the last package provides the correct links.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{libertine} % allows bf sc fonts http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98581/104449
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=\topsep, spacebelow=\topsep,
  headfont=\libertine\bfseries\scshape,
  notefont=\libertine\bfseries\scshape,
  headindent=-1em,
  headpunct=\newline,
  numberwithin=chapter,
  notebraces={- }{}
]{mythmstyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mythmstyle,name={}]{thm}
\declaretheorem[style=mythmstyle, title=Defn,name={}]{defn}

\renewcommand{\thmtformatoptarg}[1]{#1}%

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\listoftheorems[ignoreall, show={thm}]
\begingroup               % Temporarily disable \clearpage to show both lists on one page
  \let\clearpage\relax    % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14511/104449
  \renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of Definitions}
  \listoftheorems[ignoreall, show={defn}]
\endgroup


\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{}
\begin{thm}[My first theorem]
\end{thm}

\begin{defn}[My first definition]
\end{defn}

\chapter{}
\begin{thm}[My second theorem]
\end{thm}

\begin{defn}[My second definition]
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

**Update**

The `\thmt@thmname` is inside `\thmt@mklistcmd` which is only called once during a `theorem` definition. If the name isn't requested, it should be dropped. Either patch the `\thmt@mklistcmd` or redefine it:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{libertine} % allows bf sc fonts http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98581/104449
\usepackage{thmtools}


\newif\ifusethmname

\makeatletter

\renewcommand\thmt@mklistcmd{%
  \@xa\protected@edef\csname l@\thmt@envname\endcsname{% CHECK: why p@edef?
    \@nx\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{\@nx\thmt@listnumwidth}%
  }%
  \ifthmt@isstarred
    \@xa\def\csname ll@\thmt@envname\endcsname{%
      \protect\numberline{\protect\let\protect\autodot\protect\@empty}%
      \ifusethmname
      \thmt@thmname
      \fi
      \ifx\@empty\thmt@shortoptarg\else\protect\thmtformatoptarg{\thmt@shortoptarg}\fi
    }%
  \else
    \@xa\def\csname ll@\thmt@envname\endcsname{%
      \protect\numberline{\csname the\thmt@envname\endcsname}%
      \ifusethmname
      \thmt@thmname
      \fi
      \ifx\@empty\thmt@shortoptarg\else\protect\thmtformatoptarg{\thmt@shortoptarg}\fi
    }%
  \fi
  \@xa\gdef\csname thmt@contentsline@\thmt@envname\endcsname{%
    \thmt@contentslineShow% default:show
  }%
}


\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=\topsep, spacebelow=\topsep,
  headfont=\libertine\bfseries\scshape,
  notefont=\libertine\bfseries\scshape,
  headindent=-1em,
  headpunct=\newline,
  numberwithin=chapter,
  notebraces={- }{}
]{mythmstyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mythmstyle, ]{thm}
\declaretheorem[style=mythmstyle, title=Defn]{defn}

\usepackage{xpatch}


\renewcommand{\thmtformatoptarg}[1]{#1}%

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\makeatletter

\makeatother
\listoftheorems[ignoreall, show={thm}]
\begingroup               % Temporarily disable \clearpage to show both lists on one page
  \let\clearpage\relax    % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14511/104449
  \renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of Definitions}
  \listoftheorems[ignoreall, show={defn}]
\endgroup


\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{}
\begin{thm}[My first theorem]
\end{thm}

\begin{defn}[My first definition]
\end{defn}

\chapter{}
\begin{thm}[My second theorem]
\end{thm}

\begin{defn}[My second definition]
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That worked nicely. Can you explain what you mean by "this has an effect to the body-text display as well"? I put in your changes, and I don't see any discernible changes in how the body text is being displayed.

Comment: @Synergist: The abbreviation `Thm` vanishes also in the body, i.e. where the Theorem really is displayed. I try to remove this 'unpleasant' feature!

Comment: @Synergist: I've found the 'error' using the `Thm` and `Defn` prefixes in the List of ... -- see the update please,

Comment: Wow, thank you! I just started using LaTeX a few months ago. So some of what you did is beyond my current scope. In particular, I have no experience with patching commands like you did. If it's not a bother, would you mind briefly explaining how you were able to track down that `\thmt@thmname` is inside `\thmt@mklistcmd`?

Comment: @Synergist: Of course I had to look into the code of `thmtools`, especially `thm-listof.sty`. Basically, any `List of...` uses `\addcontentsline` → look for this code and trace back, here the `ll@....` command which does the real display and spacings` is of interest -- there I found `\thmt@thmname` to be the 'villain'. But it took some minutes to understand that `\thmt@mklistcmd` had to be changed before the definitions of the theorems, definitions etc. occur!

Comment: @Synergist: And ToC's are my favourite ;-)

Comment: Thanks, that's very insightful. And I love ToC's too...when I finally get them to work :)!

Comment: @Synergist: That's not really difficult as long as one does not violate the rules ;-)